# First and last available datapoint of a month in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

At the beginning and end of each month I need to perform a specific calculation in python. The problem is that I can not use a function like:

```
def first_day_of_year(d):
    return date(d.year, 1)
```

Since the dataframe I am using does not have datapoints for every day of the year. So how can I call the first available datapoint of a month? And how do I call the last one?

Comment: Sort them and the item at 0th position would be your required output.

Comment: thanks, but how do I sort the items of a specific month?

Comment: Provide some sample data ?

Comment: 1980-01-02    
1980-01-03    
1980-01-04    - sth like that?

1980-01-07    

1980-01-08

Comment: Are these dates store as strings for as in `datetime` format ?

Comment: something like `df.groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper('1M')).first()` should work

Comment: Thanks, Paul. If I use your function, it returns: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 8, placement implies 1

Comment: Solution was provided by MarkD: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18085/calculate-ytd-return-find-first-available-datapoint-of-a-year-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a list of `datetime` objects and you want to group them by the `.month` attribute. So, First of all you need to sort them, then you can apply `itertools.groupby()` function which returns: a group value and an iterator.

```
import itertools

#Your datetime objects
dates = []

dates.sort()

groups = itertools.groupby(time_obj_dates, key = lambda x:x.month)

for mon, dates in groups:
    for date in dates:
        print mon, ("-".join(map(str,[date.year, date.month, date.day])))

>>> 1 1980-1-1
    1 1980-1-2
    1 1980-1-3
    1 1980-1-4
    1 1980-1-7
```

So, you see from output that we grouped the dates based on month. And we had already sorted the list so, to get the started date we choose the first element in the **group** and and for last date we choose the end element of that group.

To access the starting and ending date of a given group you can use:

```
for mon,dates in groups:
   list_dates = list(dates)
   print mon, list_dates[0], list_dates[-1]
```